# Optimization problem

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, st.statistics

I'm trying to solve a very practical optimization problem and I think I hit a dead-end.

There are $N$ products ($N \sim 50$). Each product can have a price $p_i$ in range between 1 and 40 dollars. For each product there's a non-decreasing demand function $d_i(p)$, $a > b \Rightarrow d(a) >= d(b)$. Demand functions are produced by running Monte-Carlo simulations, represented by a table and from the look of it cannot be easily approximated by something analytical and differentiable.

Total cost of all products is what is being maximized.

$\max \sum_{i} p_i d_i(p_i)$

There's only one constraint, it's a non-linear constraint on average price:

$\frac{\sum_{i} p_i d_i(p_i))}{\sum_{i} v_i d_i(p_i)} \le C$

where $v_i$ is a constant specified in advance for each product.

Any suggestions? I tried some heuristics, but results are highly unstable. Small change in $C$ leads to very different results.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What would constitute a "solution" for you?  Do you want some method with some type of performance guarantee (hard if you can't tell us anything about the form of the $d_i$)?  Or suggestions for other heuristics?  Without knowing more, the question is not clearly appropriate for this site.

Comment: Not much to tell about $d_i$, unfortunately. Monotonically non-decreasing, not necessarily convex. Any suggestions are welcome, even for other heuristics.

I was wondering if that was the question for MathOverflow. Would highly appreciate if someone sends me in a right direction as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend first thinking carefully about the trivial case $N=1$ and the nontrivial case $N=2$.

For $N=1$, the constraint is simply $pd(p) \le Cvd(p)$, so it's pretty clear that you'll maximize $pd(p)$ when $p=Cv$ (since $d$ is non-decreasing).

For $N=2$, the constraint is

$$pd_1(p) + qd_2(q) \le Cv_1d_1(p)+Cv_2d_2(q).$$

(I'm writing $p$ and $q$ for $p_1$ and $p_2$ here, to reduce the number of subscripts.)  Now let $p=Cv_1+x$ and $q=Cv_2-y$.  The constraint boils down to one relating $x$ and $y$:

$$xd_1(Cv_1+x) \le yd_2(Cv_2-y).$$

Given that the demand functions $d_1$ and $d_2$ are unspecified (beyond being non-decreasing), I don't see how you can hope to say much about where the max is achieved.  But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Here's one example of what the demand function might look like:
http://imgur.com/FFklmWW

As you can see, that's pretty irregular.

Clearly, there has to be some kind of a search algorithm involved. Maybe starting with $Cv_i$ price vector and searching around that point. I guess the question is how to make this search efficient.